CORS blocking from crowcpp
I was trying to set the cors of crowcpp according to their example: crowcpp cors example as
app.cpp:
#include "app.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include "crow.h"
#include <crow/middlewares/cors.h>

#include <c1/authentication/authentication_controller.hpp>
#include <c1/user/user_controller.hpp>

namespace c1
{
void App::run()
{
    std::vector<Controller*> controllers{
        new AuthenticationController(""),
        new UserController("user")
    };

    crow::App<crow::CORSHandler> app;
    auto& cors = app.get_middleware<crow::CORSHandler>();
    cors
        .global()
        .origin("http://localhost:3000")
        .methods("POST"_method, "GET"_method, "PUT"_method, "DELETE"_method)
        .allow_credentials();

    for (const auto i : controllers)
    {
        app.register_blueprint(i->get());
        i->setRoutes();
    }

    app.port(4567).multithreaded().run();
}
} // c

but still get
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4567/sign-up. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed). Status code: 404.

so I tried to adjust the crow::response headers:
authentication_controller.cpp:
#include "authentication_controller.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <crow/app.h>

namespace c1
{
void AuthenticationController::setRoutes()
{
    CROW_BP_ROUTE(get(), "/sign-up").methods(crow::HTTPMethod::Post)([](const crow::request& req, crow::response& res)
    {
        const auto json = crow::json::load(req.body);
        std::cout << json << std::endl;
        res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
        res.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    });
}
} // c

but still the same error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4567/sign-up. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed). Status code: 404.

So what should I do?
backend
frontend

Which version of Crow are you using? Also, you seem to be making request from port 4567 but the accepted origin is set to 3000.

The issue was already fixed in Crow in their last release: https://github.com/CrowCpp/Crow/issues/764

@kiner_shah how exactly? So what should I change in the above code? The provided github link has similar cors definition. The poster there, had some problem with Access-Control-Max-Age, which is not my case so is not applicable

@milanHrabos upgrade to crow 1.1.0

@milanHrabos if you are using an older version of Crow, just update the version to latest one and check if it fixes things. If there is a reason you can't update to latest version, then maybe try this hack (not recommended for production system).
